# LWC on lightning record pages for mobile devices

Tags: lightning-web-components

I created a LWC and added in record pages.It works fine for `Desktop` users but it is not available to `mobile` users. As per salesforce documentation of [Form Factors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_config_form_factors),

> Record and Home pages support only the Large form factor.

Is there a workaround for this because it doesn't make sense that users cannot see LWC in record pages in mobile devices.